# How can I get trigger signal for disabled QAction element?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, qaction

I have disabled QAction menu element:

```
QAction *item = new QAction(itemTitle);
item->setEnabled(false);
```

I use SLOT connection to call function after element was pressed, but it's works **only for enabled** elements:

```
QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(func()));
```

My question is **how can I trigger some function for disabled QAction element**?

Qt 5.9.2, MSVC2017 64bit compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `setEnabled()` property holds whether the widget is enabled.
>
> In general an enabled widget handles keyboard and mouse events; a
>   **disabled widget does not**. An exception is made with QAbstractButton.

When a widget is disable, all mouse and keyboard events are also disable.

More info : http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#enabled-prop

Comment: so there is no way to do that? what if somehow simulate disabled QAction element with QT stylesheet, but not with `setEnabled()` itself, is this way is possible?

Comment: CSS disable is the same. maybe you could change `backcolor`, `border`, `reimplement events` to kinda simulate disable. other wise not possible.

Comment: I suggest you to find another way, why you need to trigger disabled widget?

Comment: The idea is that I have some list of filenames and if file is not downloaded it is displaying as disabled. If use click on disabled element, the file begins to download. Generally, downloaded files are active in menu, undownloaded are disabled.

Comment: It's kinda your opinion to how to simulate a disable button. maybe this help you. `QColor color = ui->btnDisable->palette().button().color();` and `ui->btnEnable->setStyleSheet("background-color:" + color.name() +";");`